# Wagtail menu: add or move items

Tags: django, menu, doc, wagtail

I'm creating website with Wagtail and i'd like to understand menu wagtail-way. I found solutions with templatetags or with menu-items. This is simple and working. But Wagtail solves if i need to add some item (link to external site, link to webpage with filters aso...) and how menu can be rearanged? I'm tried to search Wagtail "doc", but it keeps talking just about admin menu and for simple menu there nothing more than few simple hints about parent and children of the Page.

Thanks for any advice or link to doc.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Wagtail itself does not include menu management features. If modifying templates to manipulate menus is not an adequate solution (e.g. site editors will need to modify the menu in the future), you will have to either create your own custom logic or use an external library like https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus.

Comment: Thanks, i already used method via templatetags shown in wagtail-demo. Hope, there will be better solution in near future buil-in.